# Error(500) While Publishing the JSON Payload by Mule Anypoint MQ Publish component ( Mule 4)

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

Error Message while publishing a JSON payload with the Publish operation of the Anypoint MQ connector:

```
"Failed to publish message to destination 'ABC-queue': An error occurred while executing the operation: SEND ONE MESSAGE. Cause: 500 - Internal Server Error ({
  "status" : "failure",
  "statusMessage" : "Unexpected error"
}).
```

The sample JSON payload which I am trying to publish with the Anypoint MQ Publish operation:

```json
{
    "MATNR": "1234567",
    "GTIN": "4008429116254",
    "version": "4",
    "packtype": "1",
    "consumerpacktype": "1",
    "declaredweight": "70 g ℮",
    "importer-P-IT-PED": "Mars Italia S.p.A., Viale Milanofiori Strada 2 - Palazzo C3, 20090 Assago (MI), Servizio Consumatori: 800 30 31 30, www.pedigree.it",
    "importer-P-ES-PED": "Mars Multisales Spain S.L. Plaza de Carlos Trías Bertrán, 4, 1ªplanta, 28020 Madrid Tel. 900 10 27 98, www.pedigree.es",
    "importer-P-PT-PED": "Mars Portugal Inc., Torre Monsanto, Rua Afonso Praça 30, 10.º andar, Miraflores, 1495-061 Algés, Portugal 21 458 11 67, www.pedigree.pt",
    "importer-P-GR-PED": "Εισαγωγή: Mars Hellas A.E., 19,3χλμ Λ.Μαρκοπούλου, Παιανία 19002 210 8196200, www.pedigree.gr, 00220020000119",
    "ADDITIVES": {
      "el": "<b>Πρόσθετες ύλες ανά kg:</b>",
      "pt": "<b>Aditivos por kg:</b>",
      "es": "<b>Aditivos por kg:</b>",
      "it": "<b>Integrazioni per kg:</b>"
    },
    "PRESERVATIVES": {
      "el": "Συντηρητικά",
      "pt": "Conservantes",
      "es": "Conservantes",
      "it": "Conservanti"
    },
    "NUTRITIONAL-ADDITIVES": {
      "el": "Διατροφικές πρόσθετες ύλες:",
      "pt": "Aditivos nutricionais:",
      "es": "Aditivos nutricionales:",
      "it": "Additivi nutrizionali:"
    },
    "VITA-": {
      "el": "Βιταμίνη A: 4992 IU",
      "pt": "Vitamina A: 4992 UI",
      "es": "Vitamina A: 4992 UI",
      "it": "Vitamina A: 4992 U.I."
    },
    "CHOCAL": {
      "el": "Βιταμίνη D₃: 499 IU",
      "pt": "Vitamina D₃: 499 UI",
      "es": "Vitamina D₃: 499 UI",
      "it": "Vitamina D₃: 499 U.I."
    },
    "VITE-": {
      "el": "Βιταμίνη E: 52.0 mg",
      "pt": "Vitamina E: 52.0 mg",
      "es": "Vitamina E (alfa-tocoferoles): 52.0 mg",
      "it": "Vitamina E: 52.0 mg"
    },
    "ANALYTICAL-CONSTITUENTS": {
      "el": "<b>Αναλυτικά στοιχεία (%):</b>",
      "pt": "<b>Constituintes analíticos (%):</b>",
      "es": "<b>Constituyentes analíticos (%):</b>",
      "it": "<b>Componenti analitici (%):</b>"
    },
    "PRO-": {
      "el": "πρωτεΐνη: 42.0",
      "pt": "proteína: 42.0",
      "es": "proteína: 42.0",
      "it": "proteina grezza: 42.0"
    },
    "FAT": {
      "el": "ολικές λιπαρές ουσίες: 22.0",
      "pt": "matéria gorda: 22.0",
      "es": "contenido en grasa: 22.0",
      "it": "oli e grassi grezzi: 22.0"
    },
    "INORGANIC-MATTER": {
      "el": "ανόργανη ύλη: 7.5",
      "pt": "matéria inorgânica: 7.5",
      "es": "materia inorgánica: 7.5",
      "it": "ceneri grezze: 7.5"
    },
    "FIBTG": {
      "el": "ολική ινώδης ουσία: 1.0",
      "pt": "fibra bruta: 1.0",
      "es": "fibra bruta: 1.0",
      "it": "fibra grezza: 1.0"
    },
    "MOISTURE": {
      "el": "υγρασία: 27.0",
      "pt": "humidade: 27.0",
      "es": "humedad: 27.0",
      "it": "umidità: 27.0"
    },
    "ENER-": {
      "el": "Ενέργεια: 360 kcal/100 g",
      "pt": "valor energético: 360 kcal/100 g",
      "es": "energía: 360 kcal/100 g",
      "it": "valore energetico: 360 kcal/100 g"
    },
    "INSTR-SHORT-SENTENCES": {
      "el": [
        "Μικρόσωμοι σκύλοι, π.χ. Ντάκσχουντ, προσφέρετε έως μισή λιχουδιά την ημέρα.",
        "Μεσαίου μεγέθους σκύλοι, π.χ. Κόκερ Σπάνιελ, προσφέρετε έως και 1 τεμάχιο την ημέρα.",
        "Μεγάλου μεγέθους σκύλοι, π.χ. Λαμπραντόρ, προσφέρετε έως 2 λιχουδιές την ημέρα.",
        "Παρακαλούμε μειώστε την πλήρη τροφή ανάλογα.",
        "Φυλάσσεται σε ξηρό και δροσερό χώρο.",
        "Διατηρήστε καλά σφραγισμένο και χρησιμοποιήστε μέσα σε 2 εβδομάδες από το άνοιγμα.",
        "Έχετε πάντα διαθέσιμο φρέσκο, πόσιμο νερό."
      ],
      "pt": [
        "Cães de raça pequena (ex: Teckel) dê até meio snack por dia.",
        "Cães de raça média (ex: Cocker Spaniel) dê até 1 snack por dia.",
        "Cães de raça grande (ex: Labrador) dê até 2 snacks por dia.",
        "Reduza a quantidade de ração em conformidade.",
        "Guardar num local fresco e seco.",
        "Uma vez aberto, manter bem fechado e consumir dentro de 2 semanas.",
        "Tenha sempre à disposição um recipiente com água limpa e fresca."
      ],
      "es": [
        "Perros de tamaño pequeño, como un Teckel, dar hasta media pieza al día.",
        "Perros de tamaño mediano, como un Cocker Spaniel, dar hasta 1 pieza al día.",
        "Perros de tamaño grande, como un Labrador, dar hasta 2 piezas al día.",
        "Reducir la comida principal en consecuencia.",
        "Mantener en un lugar fresco y seco.",
        "Una vez abierto, consérvelo herméticamente cerrado y consúmalo en las próximas 2 semanas.",
        "Dejar siempre abundante agua fresca disponible."
      ],
      "it": [
        "Cani di taglia piccola, es. Bassotto, dare fino a mezzo pezzo al giorno.",
        "Cani di taglia media, es. Cocker Spaniel, dare fino a 1 pezzo al giorno.",
        "Cani di taglia grande, es. Labrador, dare fino a 2 pezzi al giorno.",
        "Adattate il pasto principale di conseguenza.",
        "Da conservare in luogo fresco ed asciutto.",
        "Una volta aperto, richiudere accuratamente e consumare entro 2 settimane.",
        "Lasciare sempre a disposizione dell'abbondante acqua fresca."
      ]
    },
    "Classifications": [
      "Pedigree_Ranchos_Lamb_Co-man_v4:C&T,Dog,Adult,Dry"
    ],
    "Languages": [
      "Italian",
      "Spanish",
      "Portuguese",
      "Greek"
    ],
    "Markets": [
      "Italy",
      "Spain",
      "Portugal",
      "Greece"
    ],
    "Brand": [
      "Pedigree_Ranchos_Lamb_Co-man_v4:Pedigree"
    ],
    "Nutritional Status": {
      "it": [
        "<b>Alimento complementare per cani adulti.</b>"
      ],
      "es": [
        "<b>Alimento complementario para perros adultos.</b>"
      ],
      "pt": [
        "<b>Alimento composto complementar para cães adultos.</b>"
      ],
      "el": [
        "<b>Συμπληρωματική τροφή για ενήλικους σκύλους.</b>"
      ]
    },
    " Best Before": {
      "it": [
        "Da consumarsi preferibilmente entro/Lotto di produzione:vedere retro della confezione.Numero di identificazione stabilimento: AT HT30906 EG."
      ],
      "es": [
        "Fecha de consumo preferente / número de lote:ver reverso del envase.Código de Identificación de Fábrica: AT HT30906 EG."
      ],
      "pt": [
        "Data de utilização preferencial/Nº de lote:ver verso da embalagem.Número de indentificação de Fábrica: AT HT30906 EG."
      ],
      "el": [
        "Ανάλωση κατά προτίμηση πριν από/κωδικός παραγωγής:βλ. στην πίσω πλευρά της συσκευασίας.Αριθμός Μητρώου Εργοστασίου: AT HT30906 EG."
      ]
    },
    "Ingredients / Composition": {
      "it": [
        "<b>Composizione</b>:carni e derivati (totale 95%, di cui agnello 15%), sostanze minerali, oli e grassi."
      ],
      "es": [
        "<b>Composición</b>:carnes y subproductos animales (total 95%, incluye cordero 15%), sustancias minerales, aceites y grasas."
      ],
      "pt": [
        "<b>Composição</b>:carnes e derivados de animal (total 95%, inclui borrego 15%), substâncias minerais, óleos e gorduras."
      ],
      "el": [
        "<b>Σύνθεση</b>:κρέας και ζωικά παράγωγα (συνολικά 95%, εκ των οποίων αρνάκι 15%), μεταλλικά στοιχεία, έλαια και λίπη."
      ]
    },
    "Variety Claim": {
      "it": [
        " ricco di agnello"
      ],
      "es": [
        " rico en cordero"
      ],
      "pt": [
        " rico em borrego"
      ],
      "el": [
        " πλούσιο σε αρνάκι"
      ]
    },
    "Symbol Codes": [
      "S163 IT LICENCEPLATE",
      "S308 INVOLUCRO PLASTICA 7"
    ],
    "Usage and Consumption claims": {
      "it": [
        "Per evitare il rischio di soffocamento, tenere la confezione lontano dalla portata dei bambini e degli animali domestici."
      ],
      "es": [
        "Para evitar riesgo de asfixia, mantenga la bolsa fuera del alcance de bebés, niños pequeños y mascotas."
      ],
      "pt": [
        "Para evitar asfixia, mantenha as embalagens afastadas de bebés, crianças e animais de estimação."
      ],
      "el": [
        "Για την αποφυγή κινδύνου ασφυξίας, κρατάτε τις σακούλες μακριά από μωρά, μικρά παιδιά και κατοικίδια ζώα."
      ]
    }
  }
```

The above JSON  payload contains special characters because the payload contains the data for different languages.

Since the payload is of different language based on the country code, so I am getting error while publishing the data to Anypoint MQ.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't fail when there are no special characters? Does it fail when there are no special characters? Does the error message has more lines?

Comment: Yes I have checked that , when the payload contains only English characters , then it is getting published to Anypoint MQ . Also whatever I have mentioned is the complete error message . That's all I am getting as error.

Comment: Please let me know if there are any other details required for troubleshooting

Comment: This question needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the payload is a valid JSON but Any point MQ doesn't like some characters. The error message should be clearer. I recommend reporting the issue to MulesSoft for further analysis. In the meantime you may be able to escape national characters as Unicode escapes (\uHHHH) using Java or Groovy code an see if that works.